# Setting a variable with javascript submit with form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I have three hidden variables on a form. I have to set these variables using a javascript function then I have to reload the page so I can use the form variables with some php code.

The problem I'm having is that, first, I don't know when I should call the javascript function. I managed to call it once I submit the form but then I can't get the page to refresh. So then I let the javascript function run when the page is first loaded but then I think the variables of the hidden fields are not properly set.

Here is my javascript code, the first version. In this version I have a gps function which is called once the form is submitted.

```
<script>

function gps(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation, showError);
    }
    else {
      alert('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');
    }

}

function GetLocation(location) {

    document.getElementById("latitude").value=location.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value=location.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("accuracy").value=location.coords.accuracy;

}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is my form code simplified

```
<form id="emoteForm" action="" onsubmit="gps(); return false;" target="_top" method="post" name="emote">

<input hidden="true" type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude">
<input hidden="true" type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude">
<input hidden="true" type="text" id="accuracy" name="accuracy">

<h4><input id="but" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="show('form'); return FALSE;"></h4>

</form>
```

Now this is the php code that is before the html code of this page and that I have to run after the submission of the form.

```
<?PHP

session_start();

if(!isset($latitude)){
    echo "Do something";
}

if(postvar("submit")=="Submit"){
     echo "Submitting";
}

?>
```

So when I first load the page I get the "Do something" text which is fine since the latitude variable is still not set. When I hit the Submit button I get asked to allow to get my GPS location since it is calling the gps() function. In this function the variables latitude, longitude and accuracy are set. But then the page doesn't reload.

How can I then do both things, set the variable values when I submit then reload the page and keep the values so I can use them with my php code. Any ideas?

EDIT 1:

Added code to control if location is already set

```
<script>

function gps(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      if (typeof localStorage['authorizedGeoLocation'] == "undefined" || localStorage['authorizedGeoLocation'] == "0") {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation, showError);
      return false;
      }else{
      return true;}
    }
    else {
      alert('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');
    }

}

function GetLocation(location) {

    document.getElementById("latitude").value=location.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value=location.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("accuracy").value=location.coords.accuracy;

    localStorage['authorizedGeoLocation'] = 1;

    document.getElementById("emoteForm").submit();

}

}

function showError(error) {
    localStorage['authorizedGeoLocation'] = 0;
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this by getting the location data before submitting the form. So I got rid of the `gps()` function and submitted the form normally. Like this.

```
<script>

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  document.getElementById("but").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("but").value = "GPS information is loading";
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation, showError);
}
else {
  document.getElementById("but").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("but").value = "No GPS information";
  alert('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');
}

function GetLocation(location) {

    document.getElementById("latitude").value=location.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value=location.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("accuracy").value=location.coords.accuracy;

    document.getElementById("but").disabled = false;  
    document.getElementById("but").value = "Submit";
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are cancelling the form submission when you use `onsubmit="gps(); return false;"` and that is correct; the `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous so you have to wait until it is finished, you can't submit the form right away.

When `getCurrentPosition()` is finished, the `GetLocation()` function gets called and the variables are filled in. Now you can submit the form so that a request to the server is made that includes the newly set values:

```
function GetLocation(location) {

    document.getElementById("latitude").value=location.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value=location.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("accuracy").value=location.coords.accuracy;

    // submit the form
    document.getElementById('emoteForm').submit();

}
```

Note that this could take some time, so you should probably show your visitor a message that the form is being submitted, disable the submit button, etc..

Comment: I tried your suggestion but after I submit the form within the javascript code how can I reload the page? I tried printing the latitude value within the php code using echo $_POST['latitude'] to check if the value was well set but it didn't even reload the page I think. Should I add anything else to the form code??

Comment: @Atirag Submitting the form should reload the page. Unless you enter in a loop where the location gets requested again and the submit cancelled. If that is the case, you should keep track of the status (location set or not) and only cancel the default submit if it is not yet set. You could put that logic in the `gps()` function using something like `onsubmit="return gps();"`. There you check if the location is already set and if it is, you just return `true`.

Comment: I did that and now it reloads the page and the latitude variable exists but it's empty since it doesn't ask me to allow to share my gps location before reloading the page. I added how I control if the location exists to the original post. Any idea how I can tell it to wait for the geolocation thing before finishing??

Comment: @Atirag Are you returning `false` if it needs to get the location? And you should check the values of your variables to see if they are set correctly.

Comment: But if I return false how can I then submit the form from within the javascript?? or should I just return false and delete the submit code??

Comment: @Atirag I just noticed your edit, you are returning `false`. Did you change the inline javascript on the form as well? And you should probably not use localstorage but a normal variable, at least while you are testing.

Comment: Yes I did, from `gps(); return false;` to `return gps();`. I also changed it now to a normal variable like you suggested.